# If $G=(A×B)\rtimes(C×D);$ $|A|=5,|B|=7,|C|=2,|D|=3,$ $C$ induces inversion on $A×B$, & $D$ acts nontriv on $B$, then ${\rm cs}^*(G)=\{2,6,7,14,35\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

I'm trying to understand how the author calculates the conjugacy sizes here:

> Consider $G= (A \times B) \rtimes (C \times D)$, where $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are cyclic groups of order 5, 7, 2, 3,
> respectively, $C$ induces the inversion map on $A \times B$, and $D$ acts nontrivially on $B$. Then $\operatorname{cs}^*(G)=\{2, 6, 7, 14, 35\}$.

Here the $\operatorname{cs}^*(G)$ is the set of all sizes of conjugacy classes of $G$ except $1$.

I am somehow new to semidirect products but I think I understand the semidirect product here. I tried to check when an element commutes with another. But it gets so complicated and confusing and I can't get anywhere. I appreciate any tip on how to approach this.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: The semidirect product is not associative. You should really include parentheses there.

Comment: @shaun Yeah, I just copied that and forgot to sort that part out. My bad. Thank you for editing.

Comment: I don't think it is too difficult to see that the orders of the elements are $1,2,3,5,6,7,15,35$. If you work systematically through these I think you'll find that their centralisers have orders $210, 6, 30, 105, 30, 35, 15, 35$. I don't think there's any clever way to tackle it, it's just a question of keeping your nerve.

Comment: Following the comment by @ancientmathematician, all you need to prove is that for any $g\in G$, $|C_{G}(g)|\notin \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 14, 21, 42, 70\}$. Obviously $|C_{G}(g)|\notin \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7\}$. I'll prove $|C_{G}(g)|\ne 42$, by the same discussion we get the result for other cases. Assume $|C_{G}(g)|= 42$, we see that $C_{G}(g)\cong C_{7}\rtimes C_{6}$, where $C_{6}$ acts Frobeniusly on $C_{7}$. Since $g\in C_{G}(g)$, $o(g)\in \{2,3,6,7\}$. Easily we get that there exists an element of order $14$ or $21$ in $C_{G}(H)$, a contradiction.